# Comparing two groups with multiple variables using anova or another testing method in r

Tags: r, comparison, anova

Working on my master thesis right now. I have 2 groups: Showering as usual and Cold shower group. Variables are age, gender, weight, psychological wellbeing, physiological wellbeing, sleep quality, movement behvaior, skin texture, shower behavior etc.

Head(data1)

`Code Gruppe StudentBasel Alter Grösse Gewicht0W Gewicht12W
1 TURN12      2           Ja    50    159        70         72
2 AMMN17      1         Nein    26    164        52         50
3 LKPG08      2         Nein    19    167        54         NA
4 LJRn05      2         Nein    22    180        60         NA
5 AGBD08      1         Nein    24    165        49         NA
6 IUGH20      2         Nein    32    168        54         NA
  Geschlecht WHO1W WHO4W WHO8W WHO12W FEW1W FEW4W FEW8W FEW12W
1          w     6    21    24     25    87    70    80     75
2          w    24    22    25     22    77    78    83     74
3          w    16    NA    NA     NA    65    NA    NA     NA
4          w    19    NA    NA     NA    61    NA    NA     NA
5          w    23    18    22     NA    61    61    56     NA
6          w    22    NA    NA     NA    66    NA    NA     NA
  SchlafA1W SchlafA4W SchlafA8W SchlafA12W SchlafWT1W SchlafWT4W
1        32        25        25         30         49         32
2        35        31        35         28         46         43
3        28        NA        NA         NA         31         NA
4        23        NA        NA         NA         32         NA
5        27        28        26         NA         35         34
6        27        NA        NA         NA         41         NA`

So. I have two groups and data from the 4th, 8th and 12th week. I want to compare the groups by the means on the 4th week. Running t-tests for every variable was not suggested because of some error i'm not considering. So I thought, I'll use an ANOVA like this

`CSSAUW4 <- aov(formula = Gruppe ~ WHO4W + FEW4W + Dauer4W + SchlafA4W + SchlafWT4W + Einschlafzeit4W + Schwitzen + Haut4W + KHaut4W + Abwesenheit4W + Krankheitssymptome4W + Duschhäufigkeit4W,
              data = Group4W)`

So I got all my results and was pretty happy, but I wasn't able to conduct a TukeyHSD() test, cause "Group" was not a factor. So changed it to factor a factor with as.factor(), but now I can't calculate my ANOVA anymore. Apparently I did it all wrong and should have used a aov(numeric variable ~ group) to compare everything, but then I got the same problem like on the variant with the t-test to write every code for every single variable.

So I read something about lme4 ANOVA's but I find it really difficult to understand how to code it for my data since i successfully dodged every R course in my university. 
I'd like to have some simple coding like: Test(Group ~ variable1, variable2, variable3, data=data1) and that's it. For Week4, Week8, Week12.

I was thinking of using lm(group ~ variable1, variable2, etc.) instead. Would that be possible and make sense for my data? I'm doubting my statistical intelligence is right on that one :D

Second question: I have the problem of having a little dataset (loss to follow up for the 12th week of 90%). So at the moment I got only 8 participants in each group. Can I do the same mean comparison on the 12th week like on the 4th week (with 25 participants each)?

Help would be really appreciated!!

Greetings Christian

Comment: you got your formula the wrong way around. The dependent variable is on the left not the right

Comment: I can write something below with simulated data and that can get you started please focus your question to 1 problem

Comment: One Way to compare all the variables by groupe

Comment: ok so let's say WHO4W by group?

Comment: Would be aov(formula = WHO4W ~ Gruppe, data = data1), right? But then I need to calculate every dependent variable individually. And this also for week8 and 12. Isn't there a much simpler way and is it statistically correct to do so?

Comment: this is correct for one comparison. For what you are doing, you can also do pairwise.t.test, see below:

Answer (score 3):

Example data:

```
set.seed(100)
data1 = data.frame(
Code =sample(letters,100,replace=TRUE),
Gruppe=sample(1:2,100,replace=TRUE),
matrix(rpois(100*11,100),nrow=100)) 
colnames(data1)[-c(1:2)] = c("StudentBasel","Alter","Grösse",
"WHO1W","WHO4W","WHO8W","WHO12W","FEW1W","FEW4W","FEW8W","FEW12W")
```

You can select the columns you want to test:

```
test_columns = c("WHO4W","WHO8W","WHO12W")
```

So, if you just want to test say 4,8 and 12 together, for WHO4 series, you do, the select command essentially selects the columns you want to test:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

data1 %>% 
select(c("Gruppe",test_columns)) %>% 
pivot_longer(-Gruppe)

# A tibble: 300 x 3
   Gruppe name   value
    <int> <chr>  <int>
 1      2 WHO4W     97
 2      2 WHO8W     91
 3      2 WHO12W    93
 4      1 WHO4W     99
 5      1 WHO8W    103
 6      1 WHO12W    92
 7      2 WHO4W     91
 8      2 WHO8W    111
 9      2 WHO12W   120
10      1 WHO4W    119
# … with 290 more rows
```

In the above step, I basically repeated for joined every week with its corresponding Gruppe, this is called pivoting a table into long format.

So what you want to do, is a test for Gruppe, within every variable, and you can do it by grouping it first (group_by) followed by the aov as you do by contained within a "do", which means do aov on every group:

```
result = data1 %>% 
select(c("Gruppe",test_columns)) %>% 
pivot_longer(-Gruppe) %>% 
group_by(name) %>% 
do(tidy(aov(value ~ Gruppe,data=.))) 

# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups:   name [3]
  name   term         df    sumsq meansq statistic p.value
  <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 WHO12W Gruppe        1   131.   131.      1.25     0.266
2 WHO12W Residuals    98 10247.   105.     NA       NA    
3 WHO4W  Gruppe        1   111.   111.      1.01     0.316
4 WHO4W  Residuals    98 10740.   110.     NA       NA    
5 WHO8W  Gruppe        1     1.63   1.63    0.0169   0.897
6 WHO8W  Residuals    98  9428.    96.2    NA       NA
```

Now we simply take out on terms that contain Gruppe, we are not interested in the residuals:

```
result %>% filter(term=="Gruppe")
# A tibble: 3 x 7
# Groups:   name [3]
  name   term      df  sumsq meansq statistic p.value
  <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 WHO12W Gruppe     1 131.   131.      1.25     0.266
2 WHO4W  Gruppe     1 111.   111.      1.01     0.316
3 WHO8W  Gruppe     1   1.63   1.63    0.0169   0.897
```

I suggest this above because it is easier to explain to people what you have done (you cannot say I did an anova..), and easier to interpret. You can use a big aov and do a posthoc, but please read up and understand what anova is doing before applying this:

```
#pivot long like before
aov_df = data1 %>% 
select(c("Gruppe",test_columns)) %>% 
pivot_longer(-Gruppe)
# now we have a sub group for every measurement, eg. group 1 + wk4, group #2 + wk4 and so on
aov_df$subgroup = paste0(aov_df$name,aov_df$Gruppe)

result = TukeyHSD(aov(value ~ subgroup,data=aov_df))
# the below are the meaningful comparisons you need:
result$subgroup[c("WHO12W2-WHO12W1","WHO4W2-WHO4W1","WHO8W2-WHO8W1"),]
                      diff       lwr      upr     p adj
WHO12W2-WHO12W1  2.2938808 -3.560239 8.148000 0.8711455
WHO4W2-WHO4W1    2.1151369 -3.738983 7.969256 0.9052955
WHO8W2-WHO8W1   -0.2560386 -6.110158 5.598081 0.9999956
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I'm afraid I don't get it. What stands aov_df for in my data set? df is your example data, there I should insert my data. For the rest I don't know what I need to change to make the code work. The second line is changing group to a factor, could you explaine the other lines? Thank you

Comment: @ChristianDePierro, ok i edited the answer. see whether it makes sense now